# Visual Studio 2017 VC++ platform toolset v141 slower than v100, why?

Tags: c, visual-studio, optimization, compiler-optimization

I was rewriting some S3TC algorithm, and while profiling optimizations that I was testing, I was using vs2010. After I was finished writing code, decided to profile it on platform tool-set v141. Cloned separate solution, and project files as clones of original, and loaded solution into vs2017. Retargeted profiled project to platform tool-set v141, Windows SDK 10, clean and rebuilt everything, did it several times...

Profiling resulted by drop in performance for **Release** version only, while Debug version had very similar values to vs2010 debug. Measured drop in **Release** version was ~11% and holding. Checked optimizations in project properties. And everything was exactly same as in vs2010.
After which I've re-targeted back to platform tool-set v100, leaving Windows SDK 10 and rebuild everything all over again. Profiling resulted same result as vs2010 profiling. Went back to v141 registering drop of ~11% in performance. Which tells me that platform tool-set v141 has less efficient c/c++ compiler in comparison with v100 platform tool-set.

Have someone encountered this before, and discovered the reason for such behavior newer generation of compiler has?

Have any done any Preprocessing to file and comparing codes from both, and figuring out what v141 is missing?

Is this downfall of excellent coders in MS compiler team, or I am missing something here?

Comment: I've heard that Microsoft has added mitigations against speculative execution exploits, like Spectre, into their C++ libraries.  Those may cost a performance hit.

Comment: What are you using for profiling - is it VS10 profiler for the VS10 exe and VS17 profiler for the VS17 exe or is it an independent profiler

Comment: Independent profiler of course, how else to correctly measure this ;) it involves massive number of test >1 mil, and output or results with average, std. deviation and min and max deviation in results.

Answer (score 3):

Exploits against Speculative Execution in CPUs have been in the news lately, with famous examples being Spectre and Meltdown.

One way these are being addressed are in the compiler

[Understanding the performance impact of Spectre and Meltdown mitigations on Windows Systems](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2018/01/09/understanding-the-performance-impact-of-spectre-and-meltdown-mitigations-on-windows-systems/)

"Here is the summary of what [Microsoft has] found so far:

•With Windows 10 on newer silicon (2016-era PCs with Skylake, Kabylake or newer CPU), benchmarks show single-digit slowdowns, but we don’t expect most users to notice a change because these percentages are reflected in milliseconds.

•With Windows 10 on older silicon (2015-era PCs with Haswell or older CPU), some benchmarks show more significant slowdowns, and we expect that some users will notice a decrease in system performance.

•With Windows 8 and Windows 7 on older silicon (2015-era PCs with Haswell or older CPU), we expect most users to notice a decrease in system performance.

•Windows Server on any silicon, especially in any IO-intensive application, shows a more significant performance impact when you enable the mitigations to isolate untrusted code within a Windows Server instance. This is why you want to be careful to evaluate the risk of untrusted code for each Windows Server instance, and balance the security versus performance tradeoff for your environment."

So it is quite possible that programs recompiled with compilers containing these mitigations will take a small performance hit.

Comment: Benchmark performed on same PC, and if silicone microcode was the cause it should be the same on both tests. Wouldn't you agree? Otherwise I do not see the point, as attacked could simply provide affected vc libs along side with his attacking program, and circumvent above patch, if patch is provided inside vc libs (or compiler). Also above attacks require knowledge of CPU specific OP's to emit cache from CPU, which would require assembly code emit, so if writing such code I would type asm code directly.

Comment: So to my opinion answer above shouldn't ever be the case. I am not sure even how did you get idea that these two are even related? Since my question is related to pure code compiled in different compilers, and these exploits exploit CPU architecture that can't patched simply by patching compilers (I would think attacker would also test if his program works at all before deploying it to wilderness).

Comment: btw found what microsoft did in compiler related to spectre (/Qspectre): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/qspectre?view=vs-2017
You can supply this switch to mitigate possible emit of your program data from CPU cache. "The /Qspectre option is off by default." ;) so this is not the case.

Comment: Have you considered that Microsoft may have had that option on when compiling their C support DLLs?  Otherwise it would be a big hole if a main application was compiled with it on, and the libraries were compiled with it off.  I suppose you could posit that there are multiple versions, similar to debugging on/off are different versions.  But I suspect not.

Comment: "true I didn't" that being said, piece of code I was profiling that I have written doesn't use any of standard libraries features, and should compile to identical machine code representation or better with newer compilers, not worse one. I could use IDA to disassemble what difference really is, but was of thought someone already knew what it is. Will see if I have enough time this week to dig difference. Never the less managed to squeeze ~23% more speed out of decompression code now I am at ~1.5GBps DXT1, ~1GBps DXT5, so slowdown by platform tool-set v141 is negligible.